# Execute an action after my nuget package is installed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

We have created a lot of NuGet packages. One of them is a tool, and it contains a special compiler and it is installed like a `dotnet tool`. The name of the command is "PolyGen".

We used a similar mechanism to what `Grpc.Tools` uses, that means we have defined .targets file inside our NugetPackage. And it works well.

But when I update my PolyGen, afterwards I have to update the dotnet tool **manually** with `dotnet tool update` command.

But I see when the `Grpc.Tools` is updated, the dotnet tool update is automatically executed. And the Package Manager console wrote the following message:

```
Executing nuget actions took 181,36 ms
```

How can we define this automatically executed command, to avoid a manual update?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `init.ps1` powershell script to accomplish this task. This script executing every time after package installed on targeted machines.

Just create file `init.ps1` in `tools/` folder of your package definition with this content:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# Write all required actions on powershell here.
```

But be aware of that `init.ps1` also **executing every time when solution opens**. If you need to execute it only one time after NuGet package installation - you can insert condition parameter and store it's value inside your package installation folder (e.g. in file).

Comment: It will only work on Windows platform. What about Linux.