# Add a logging entry to appsettings.json via a custom NuGet package

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-core-3.1

I have a NuGet package that I have created for my company.  It works great.  But it includes some code in the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.OAuthClient` namespace that is very chatty in the logs at the `Information` level.

I would like to have my NuGet package automatically add the following line:

```
"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.OAuthClient": "Error"
```

At the end of the Logging->LogLevel section of the `appsettings.json` file of the project it is installed in (if its not already there).

Or failing that, is there a way to suppress these logs down to the Error LogLevel in code?

Answer (score 0):

*It's just my personal opinion, and it doesn't answer your question directly, but it did not fit into a comment, so posting it here.*

I don't think it's up to your package to decide, what will be in the appsettings.json. There may be let's say production and test appsettings, and in test developers of some projects would actually want to see as many logs as possible.

If your package would modify it, you would take away the decision from developers who use your package. Or, imagine, the project that uses your package also used `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.OAuthClient` namespace, but for its own purposes. And developers again might want to see logs coming from that namespace.

I'd suggest just to put this info into your package's documentation, and than developers of each project shall decide for themselves, whether they want to suppress logs or not.

**Update after comment:**
Probably this will get you somewhere: http://www.roundcrisis.com/2014/08/03/Nuget-install-tricks/
The basic idea is that you can distribute init.ps1 script together with your nuget package that will run on installation of the package. And with powershell you could do pretty much anything, including replacing strings in text files.
Have a look also at this SO question: [Execute an action after my nuget package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157969/execute-an-action-after-my-nuget-package-is-installed)

Comment: If I were writing a publicly available package, I might agree.  But I am writing for my own developers.  I know that most of them will just include the NuGet and not worry about the documentation.  Normally I would just say, "Oh well, that is their loss."  But my team also runs the logging system.  Just leaving it means that the amount of data we have to hold in our logging system also goes up.  So, in the end, I am trying to protect my own system from my developers.